# how to close automatic notification drawer in broadcatreciver

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I went to when user click cancel notification action notification drawer is automatically closed

Some solution is found but it is not working for me

Like:

Get access to system status bar.

This is not public so may be deprecated in the future Object

**=> `service = context.getSystemService("statusbar");`**

Comment: post what you done

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You